# find the extended file type of a specified file ( JPEG image, TIFF Image, ...) objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, jpeg

My question is a very simple one. How can i get the extension type of a UIImage? I can only get the image as UIImage and not as its name.  The image can be static, or can be taken from the phone gallery or even from a file path. If someone could do a little help in that, it would be grateful.

```
-(returnType)functionName : (argument)UIImage

{
// code to get the extension//

return extension(as string)
}
```

this is how i wish to have it. I tried passing NSData. But either i need to do the JPEG representation or PNG representation. In both case i will either receive a jpeg extension or a png extension. Even if i pass a gif, it will be shown either jpeg or png. :( ... Please help

Comment: A `UIImage` has no type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `UIImage` you no longer have any concept of an image type.

If you read encoded image data from a file (or other source) into an `NSData` object you can inspect the data to determine the image's type. But once you have a `UIImage` you have an abstract image bitmap that has no type.

Remember, a `UIImage` can be created in memory. It never started out as a file and it never had a specific type. It's just an image. Even if you load a `UIImage` from a file, any association with the original file is lost. It's not until you choose to convert the `UIImage` to a specific format do you get a type.

Comment: in the abouve the person has mentioned l;ike, he had done something like that. So i thought there could be an answer for my question .

Comment: That link is about getting the type of a file, not a UIImage.